# How to improve the efficiency of NIntegrate on complicated functions?

Tags: matrix, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, eigenvalues, order

When solving a problem by Matlab and Mathematica both, I find the speed of `NIntegrate` are far less than `dblquad` when calling some complicated nested functions.
For example, if there is diagonalization process in integrand,
in Mathematica:

```
t = 1; chemicalpotential = 0.5; tem = 1.*10^-4; a = 1; kb = 1; dim = 2;

nf[e_, tem_] := 1/(Exp[e/(kb*tem)] + 1) // N

electronenergy[kx_, 
  ky_] := -2*t*(Cos[kx*a] + Cos[ky*a]) - chemicalpotential // N

ham[kx_, ky_, q_, l_] := ({
    {electronenergy[kx, ky], -q},
    {-Conjugate[q], l}
   }) + 41*IdentityMatrix[2]

eigensystem[kx_, ky_, q_, l_] := 
 MapAt[Composition[# - 41 &, Re], 
  Eigensystem[ham[kx, ky, q, l]], {1, All}]

fq[kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ, q_, l_] := 
 Block[{es, ev, cf}, es = eigensystem[kx, ky, q, l]; ev = es[[2]]; 
  cf = Conjugate[ev[[1, 1]]]*ev[[1, 2]]*nf[es[[1, 1]], tem] + 
    Conjugate[ev[[2, 1]]]*ev[[2, 2]]*nf[es[[1, 2]], tem]]

fl[kx_, ky_, q_, l_] := 
 Block[{es, ev, ff}, es = eigensystem[kx, ky, q, l]; ev = es[[2]]; 
  ff = Conjugate[ev[[1, 2]]]*ev[[1, 2]]*nf[es[[1, 1]], tem] + 
    Conjugate[ev[[2, 2]]]*ev[[2, 2]]*nf[es[[1, 2]], tem]]

intergrand1[kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ] := 
 1./(2. Pi)^2*jk*fq[kx, ky, q, l]

intergrand2[kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ] := 
 1./(2. Pi)^2*fl[kx, ky, q, l]

eqs[jk0_, q0_?NumericQ, 
  l0_?NumericQ] := {-q0 + 
   Block[{jk = jk0, q = q0, l = l0}, 
    NIntegrate[
     intergrand1[kx, ky], {kx, -1. Pi/a, 1. Pi/a}, {ky, -1. Pi/a, 
      1. Pi/a}, PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
       "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]], -1./2. + 
   Block[{jk = jk0, q = q0, l = l0}, 
    NIntegrate[
     intergrand2[kx, ky], {kx, -1. Pi/a, 1. Pi/a}, {ky, -1. Pi/a, 
      1. Pi/a}, PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]]}
```

and in Matlab:

```
function f=eqs(x)
global Q lambda 
Q=x(1);
lambda=x(2);
f1=Q-dblquad(@Eq_Q,-pi,pi,-pi,pi,1e-5);
f2=1/2-dblquad(@Eq_lambda,-pi,pi,-pi,pi,1e-5);
f=[f1, f2];
end

function f=Eq_Q(kx0,ky0)
global Jk T
lx=length(kx0);
f=zeros(1,lx);
for j=1:lx
    kx=kx0(j);
    ky=ky0;
    H=HMF(kx,ky);
    [U, D]=eig(H);
    nF1=1/(exp(D(1,1)/T)+1);
    nF2=1/(exp(D(2,2)/T)+1);
    f(j)=Jk*(U(1,1)'*U(2,1)*nF1+U(1,2)'*U(2,2)*nF2)/(2*pi)^2; 
end

function f=Eq_lambda(kx0,ky0)
global T 
lx=length(kx0);
f=zeros(1,lx);
for j=1:lx
    kx=kx0(j);
    ky=ky0;
    H=HMF(kx,ky);
    [U, D]=eig(H);
    nF1=1/(exp(D(1,1)/T)+1);
    nF2=1/(exp(D(2,2)/T)+1);
    f(j)=(U(2,1)'*U(2,1)*nF1+U(2,2)'*U(2,2)*nF2)/(2*pi)^2;
end

function h=HMF(kx,ky)
global Q lambda mu t
ek=-2*t*(cos(kx)+cos(ky))-mu;
h=[ek -Q;-Q' lambda];
end
```

The algorithm is simple: with a Hermitian matrix ham including parameters kx and ky, I want to diagonalize the matrix on each (kx,ky) in the region BZ=[-Pi/a,Pi/a]×[-Pi/a,Pi/a] and pick up specific elements of eigenvector on each site to build integrand then numerically integrate them over region BZ.
However, if one compares the speed of above-board codes, we can see the time cost are:

```
eqs[1, 1, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

```
{1.9487, {-0.741242, -0.37076}}
```

in MMA,
and

```
tic
eqs([1,1])
toc
```

with result 0.055124 seconds in Matlab respectively.
We can clearly see that in the same precision and accuracy setting, `NIntegrate` is much slower than in Matlab. On the other hand, if we compare the speed of diagonalization procedure in this problem, there is:

```
Block[{jk = 1., q = 1., l = 1.}, intergrand1[1, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

with out put

```
{0.0015761, 0.0060717}
```

And in Matlab,

```
tic
Eq_Q(1,1)
toc
```

within 0.003606 seconds. In all steps before integration, including diagonalization, Mma  is faster than Matlab.

However, if I use a simple elementary function cos(x)cos(y) as an example in my PC, something becomes different.
In Mathematica:

```
Do[NIntegrate[Cos[10. x] Cos[10. y], {x, -10., 10.}, {y, -10.,10.}], {10.}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The result is 1.37 second. However NIntegrate automatically symbolicly pretreats intergrand for higher efficiency, therefore I turn this option off:

```
intergrand[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Cos[10. x] Cos[10. y]/n
Block[{n = 1.}, 
  Do[NIntegrate[intergrand[x, y], {x, -10., 10.}, {y, -10., 10.}, 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
      "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}], {10.}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

And the result is 14.8435 second on my PC. I intend to use `?NumericQ` to compulsively control the order of integrand and integration.
Finally, in Matlab,

```
fun = @(x,y) cos(10*x)*cos(10*y)

for v = 1:10
   dblquad(fun,-10,10,-10,10);
end
toc
```

There is the result 17.22 seconds.

We can compare the result for elementary function. With symbolic pretreatment, `NIntegrate` is much faster, and even turning it off, in the same precision, `NIntegrate` is even a little bit faster than `dblquad`. Actually, I cannot understand the internal processes and why is there drastic difference between `NIntegrate` and `dblquad` in complicated functions. In my opinion, it possibly caused by computation order control in Mathematica, but I do not know how to optimize codes to make `NIntegrate` having comparable speed with `dblquad`.

Comment: What exactly is the reason you can not / do not want to use symbolic pre-processing?

Comment: As you can see in one of my example, the intergrand is a composite function including EigenSystem. Therefore, it is useless to pre-process this type of intergrands and just wasting time.

Comment: Then the only other option is to compile the integrand